# Laravel :Attempt to assign property of non-object

Tags: php, forms, laravel, file-upload

**Error:**

```
Attempt to assign property of non-object; ErrorException in AdminController.php line 40:
```

**AdminController:**

```
    public function createSlider(AdminRequest $request)
{
    $input = Request::all();
    Sliders::create($input);

    if (Request::hasFile('image')) {
        $imageName = Request::input('title'). '.' .
            $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $request->file('image')->move(
            base_path() . '/public/assets/image/', $imageName
        );

        $input->image = $imageName; //------------> line 40.......

    }
    $input->save();
}
```

**Html:**

```
{!!Form::open(array('url' => 'admin/new_slider', 'files' => true)) !!}
<div class = "form-group">
    {!!Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!!Form::text('title', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina tch'])!!}

    {!!Form::label('title', 'Description:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!!Form::text('description', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini '])!!}
</div>

<div class = "form-group">
    {!!Form::label('title', 'Link:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!!Form::text('link', null, ['class'=> 'input-mini'])!!}

    {!!Form::label('title', 'Image:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::file('image', ['id' => 'imgInp', 'class' => 'prev-upload']) !!}
</div>
<div class = "form-group">
    {!!Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=> 'btn btn-default'])!!}
</div>
```

{!! Form::close() !!}

I've been struggling with this all morning. I want to be able to accept a file upload along with the form information. Renaming the file is not necessary just how i thought i could get this to work. Is there a better way to do this file upload and move?

Comment: I pointed to line 40 inside of the Admin controller in the question.

Comment: Ah, i missed that. Made a slight edit so the syntax highlighter makes it more obvious

Comment: may be your image field is not right.

Comment: Ok, well for a start, using a hodge podge of local variables and static calls all refering to the same object is beyond confusing. As you are using method injection, use the `$request` variable, and remove the static `Request::` calls. This should help to clear things up a little

Answer (score 1):

I changed the format of everything and it worked.

```
 public function createSlider(AdminRequest $request)
{
    $slider = new Sliders(array(
        'title' => $request->get('title'),
        'description'  => $request->get('description'),
        'link'  => $request->get('link')
    ));

    $slider->save();

    $imageName = $slider->title .'_gin_slider'. '.' .
        $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $request->file('image')->move(
        base_path() . '/public/assets/image', $imageName
    );

    $slider->image = $imageName;

    $slider->save();

    return redirect('/admin');
}
```

Comment: Great, glad you got it working, and it is much more readable as well.

Answer (score 0):

For further reference: the issue occurs when your controller, router or middleware method does not return a valid response. You should always return a response from your root called method, whether it's actual data or a redirect. In case of middlewares it can be the request itself via Closure.

---

In case of controllers it should be:

```
public function index()
{
    return response() || redirect()->back();
}
```

In case of middlewares:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request) || response() || redirect()->back();
}
```

In case of route closures:

```
Route::get('foo/bar', function(){
    return response() || redirect()->back();
});
```

`||` means 'or'